# Downgrading python package installed locally

Tags: python, pip

In the server that work in (as do many other people) the "global" python has a certain version of a package, say 1.0.0.

I recently used `pip` to upgrade that to `1.0.2` locally for my user with the `pip install --user package==1.0.2`, which worked. However, now I want to uninstall my locally installed version and remain with the global one.

I've tried `pip uninstall --user package==1.0.2`, `pip uninstall --user package`, and a few other options but nothing seems to work. I always get this error:

```
Usage:   
  pip <command> [options]

no such option: --user
```

I also tried `pip install --user package=1.0.0` but now I have both versions installed locally and python uses the most recent.

How can I do what I want?

Comment: I always just use a virtual environment which makes this level of control simple. You make a virtual environment with the --no-site-packages and then install them from scratch as the version you want.

Comment: @SimonHobbs that is a good tip and I'll try it from now on. But for this specific I'm trying to solve it using only `pip`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this cannot be done with `pip` directly. I ended up solving it just by removing the package from `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/`. A bit more manual than I was hoping I'd have to do.

Answer (score 0):

The --user option for pip seems to have been removed but is still an option with setuptools.

So if you want to use the --user function what you can do is use `pip download` which will download the .whl file. You then need to extract the file using `wheel unpack`. I then ran python setup.py install --user (worked for numpy) and it installed the package to my home directory under .local.

I followed the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme).